# Telerik MVC controls, OnDocumentReady is firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, dom-events

I'm new to Telerik MVC controls, so this may be something simple.

I started out with making a new TelerikMvcApplication solution.

Site.Master:

```
    </div>
    <%: Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group =>
          group.Combined(true).Compress(true).Add("Index.js")) %>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.aspx:

```
    <%: Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().OnDocumentReady("Index.Init()") %>
</asp:Content>
```

Index.js:

```
var Index = function () {
    return {
        Init: function () {
            alert('1');
        }
    };
} ();
```

When I load Index.aspx, the `Init()` function in Index.js is fired twice, so I see 2 alerts one after another.  If I assign a click handler to a button inside the `Init()` function and hit the button with FireBug, it is actually showing 2 events being assigned to the button.  Why is this happening?

### Edit

After some more firebugging, I figured out that both calls to `ScriptRegistrar` are being rendered.  How do I make only master one to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, the problem was in the use of

```
<%:  %>
```

with colon.

To fix it, I removed colon character from both Master and View, and called Render() in Master.

Master:

```
<% Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group =>
   group.Combined(true).Compress(true).Add("json2.js")).Render(); %>
```

View:

```
<% Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Scripts(scripts =>
   scripts.AddGroup("IndexGroup", group =>
   group.Add("~/Scripts/Index.js"))).OnDocumentReady("Index.Init()");  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For MVC Razor ViewEngine:

```
@{
    Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().OnDocumentReady(
    @<text>
        alert('onLoaded');
    </text>);
}
```